# Printing Uncommon Characters?

Tags: c, ascii, printf

Basically I have a program that finds the most common character from the Acsii table.  And then prints the number of times the character happened, the Ascii Number, and the "character".  But I would like to know the easiest and most computer science way of printing characters such as NEWLINE "\n" or "\t". I would like to avoid typing out all of the characters like those if possible.

If you need any code let me know!
Thank you!

Comment: Either replace them with `.` to denote they are control character, or you need a manual mapping. (Printing those character out directly is also a way, but it will mess up the output).

Comment: Would there be any way of copying the Char column out of the ascii table in man ascii?

Comment: Select and copy - depend on the terminal you are using

Comment: Well Im using nano, but Im trying to learn vim

Answer (score 0):

You could always use [Caret Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation), which has a fairly simple mapping of the non-printable ASCII codes to the caret symbol '^' plus a printable ASCII character.

Comment: How would you print that? And would this avoid me typing out all of the "unprintable" characters?

Comment: Because there's a consistent relationship between the printable and non-printable ASCII codes with this notation it should simply be a matter of defining which codes are 'non-printable', calculating the corresponding printable ASCII code, and sticking a caret in front of it